# running lite-historian and mysql-historian together

Tags: volttron

Is it possible to run lite-historian and mysql-historian together, and save data to their database (SQLite and MySQL) respectively?

I had a failed with Timeout error: volttron.platform.vip.agent.core.Core object at 0. I was only able to save data into one of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you certainly can run more than one historian at a time. The platform was designed so that this was possible.

You may only specify one Agent with the identity 'platform.historian' at a time. More than one and the second one started will not be able to communicate with the platform. (This is better handled in an upcoming feature for VOLTTRON 4.0). That might be what is happening to you in this case.

Comment: Yes, I saw both historian agents have a identity platform.historian.

So, what do I do now? Can I change one of the identity to something else? Platform.historian_2, maybe?

Comment: Yes either change or comment out the identity in the new configuration file.  If commenting out the server will auto generate an identity for it.